# FreeIPA not resolving itself

Tags: domain-name-system, freeipa

I plan on using FreeIPA as my authoritative DNS server for my network.  All other records resolve just fine, however, FreeIPA is not resolving itself.

Running `dig ipa-hermes.lan.example.com` yields no A records

```
bash-5.1# dig ipa-hermes.lan.example.com @10.0.1.14

; <<>> DiG 9.16.19 <<>> ipa-hermes.lan.example.com @10.0.1.14
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 41126
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 807dd469a5469a178451c9da61831d41ae78b56eaed7d5e2 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ipa-hermes.lan.example.com. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.  3600    IN      SOA     ipa-hermes.lan.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. 1635981510 3600 900 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.1.14#53(10.0.1.14)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 03 23:37:37 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 140
```

From the IPA server shell, pinging `ipa-hermes.lan.example.com` returns the correct address, but that's because it's using `127.0.0.53` as the DNS when I dont specify a server.

Furthermore, I have a Unbound (currently unused, as DHCP sets the DNS to the FreeIPA server) on OPNSense.  Running dig using this server returns the correct A record.

```
bash-5.1# dig ipa-hermes.lan.example.com @10.0.0.1

; <<>> DiG 9.16.19 <<>> ipa-hermes.lan.example.com @10.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12014
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ipa-hermes.lan.example.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ipa-hermes.lan.example.com. 3600 IN A 10.0.1.14

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.1#53(10.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 03 23:43:00 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 81
```

Looking at the records on the IPA server, it IS there.

```
❯ ipa dnsrecord-find
Zone name: lan.example.com
  Record name: @
  A record: 10.0.0.1
  NS record: ipa-hermes.lan.example.com.

  ...other records

  Record name: ipa-ca
  A record: 10.0.1.14

  Record name: ipa-hermes
  A record: 10.0.1.14

  Record name: test
  A record: 10.0.2.2
-----------------------------
Number of entries returned 19
-----------------------------
```

Is there anything else I'm missing as to why this would not be working?

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.53` needs to point at the IPA server itself; I am not too familiar with Ubuntu OSes, but I believe this is set in `/etc/netplan/*`. Per the installation docs, your primary DNS server should be `127.0.0.1` and the secondary should be your second IPA server. After that's set, run `sudo netplan apply`.

You should have two IPA servers at a minimum so that they can reference each other and provide failover capabilities.

Take a look at Red Hat's guide on [configuring DNS for IPA](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/linux_domain_identity_authentication_and_policy_guide/installing-ipa#dns-reqshttps://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/linux_domain_identity_authentication_and_policy_guide/installing-ipa#dns-reqs) and see if that gives you a hand